# Calling another smart contract function failed

Tags: solidity, remix

I have two smart contract and I would like to call one smart contract function into another one and pass some parameter on it . But it constantly failed though I have tried to send hardcoded parameters. Sample function code looks like below

```
    function transfer(uint256 _tokenId,address _to) public returns (bool){
        
        // fetch required area of specific tokenId
        // transfer required area
        // transfer _tokenId
        uint256 requiredArea = nftpermdata[_tokenId].requiredArea;
        require(msg.sender == owners[_tokenId],"Incorrect Owner Address");
     //   require(propertyERC20.withdrawl(_to,requiredArea),"Transfer falled");
        ProjectContract(0xxxxxxxxxxa70c34B314B92531Axxxxxxxxx).withdrawl(0x786295aee765bE6f1Aab58954002xxxxxxxxx,1200);
        delete owners[_tokenId];
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] - 1;
        balances[_to] = balances[_to]+1;
        owners[_tokenId] = _to;
       
    }
}
```

When I call the withdrawal function directly from the smart contract, it succeeds but calling it from another smart contract with the same parameter results in a revert operation.

Withdrawl function in another contract looks like below

```
 function withdrawl(address _from, uint256 _amount) public onlyAdmin {
        require(balances[_from] >= _amount);
        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_amount);
        circulationsupply = circulationsupply.sub(_amount);
        emit withdraw(_from, _amount);
    }

   modifier onlyAdmin() {
        require(admins[msg.sender]);
        _;
    }
```

Can anyone help me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have any information on the error message?  Also, what is that contract your calling.  Checking those require statements is probably a good first step

Comment: Could you add the codes for the ProjectContract's withdrawl function?

Comment: what's the revert message?
calling this function from a contract will mean msg.sender will be the contract's instead of the initial EOA (tx origin). Is the contract address the owner of the _tokenId?

Comment: @thefett  I have added withdrawl function code. I think its reverting because of modifier I have added in a code . Am I right?
I will remove modifier and will try again

Comment: yup, if your contract is not the admin, the function will fail

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone . It was indeed permission related issue that caused it . It is now resolved.